# How to populate combobox in base form

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I have a base form in where I populate a combox with the following code:

```
private void FillComboBoxItemsFromResources(ComboBox comboBox, bool firstIsEmpty, bool selectFirst)
{
   var res = new Resources(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
   var cbEntries = res.GetComboBoxItems(comboBox.Name);

   if (firstIsEmpty)
   {
      cbEntries[0] = new KeyValuePair<int, string>(0, string.Empty);
   }
   comboBox.DataSource = cbEntries.ToArray();
   comboBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
   comboBox.ValueMember = "Key";

   if (selectFirst && cbEntries.Count > 0)
   {
      comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
   }

}
```

When I run the code and show the base form. -> All works.
When I inherit another form from my base form the code compiles but crashes with "Items-Collection cannot  be modified when the data source is set" in Windows form designer generated code.
How to work around this ?

Any help is highly aprreciated.
TIA acki

Comment: It's hard to know, but I can guess that happens because you are passing [ComboBox comboBox] as a parameter. maybe you use the same instance of the combobox?! BTW you can always add `combobox.DataSource = null;` before you are setting the Datasource and it should not raise this exception. another possible solution is to make the `FillComboBoxItemsFromResources` virtual and override in every instance of the derived forms.

Comment: You forgot to mention when and where you're using this code. Anyway, it appears that the base Form is trying to add Items to the ComboBox.Items collection at some point or, if you have set the ComboBox access modifier to `public`, something in the derived Form is. Of course, since you have set a DataSource, you can only add new data to the source, not to the Items collection.

Comment: As @Jimi commented there must be some other code in your base form trying to alter the datasource (probably some protected or public method triggered by the derived form)

Comment: Form is used to select customer by id, customer infos are read by webservice and can be changed. Updated infos infos are filled then into bookmarks in document. Base form fills combobox from text in ressourcefile. Derivied form has additional form fileds but does nothing with the combobox filled in base form (besides reading selected item). Code crashes in designer generated code like `this.cbSpeditionsvermerk.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
            ((object)(resources.GetObject("cbSpeditionsvermerk.Items"))),... ` generated code can be deleted but comes back when form gets changed.

Comment: As already mentioned, you cannot have a DataSource set and also add objects to the Items collection. If you have linked the ComboBox to a resource object in the designer, then remove it.

Comment: Jimi, the above displayed code is called in mybaseform_Load and it's the only location where I fill the combobox. For testing I added a new form, inherited again from mybaseform. When open inherited form and change somthing in inherited form (add control, move inherited controls to different position, the designer adds the crappy code shown above and code crashes during runtime ??

Answer (score 0):

Well after hours of trying around with rebuilding base form, rebuilding inherited form I just deleted the combobox in base form. Readded combobox into base form, uncommented code to fill combobox and now it works all as expected...